# nrwl NX - Copy task run after build

Tags: nrwl-nx

I'm writing a node application in TypeScript, and I need to copy some files from the src directory to the dist directory after it's built (for i18n). I can add a new "copy-i18n-files" task, but I want this task to be run as part of my normal `yarn nx run-many --target=build --all` execution step. Is there a way to have the build task call another task before completing? Or do I need to create my own custom executor?

Comment: I hacked around this by renaming the tasks in my project.json. I renamed the "build" task to "compile". I then renamed "copy-i18n-files" task to "build", and added a dependency on "compile". I'll leave this open as there may be a better way, but this works for now.